# C# Display only one line out of four returned

Tags: c#, regex, linq

I have a program that searches for a specific word being "weekend" from a text file. if this word is found, the program then goes through every line above it from the word weekend and reads each line for the word "MONTH". Once "Month is found , it Displays the line. Problem here is that there can be two or more "weekend" words below"Month". Instead of displaying "Month" the amount of "weekends" found, i just want to return one Month even though three or two weekends were found like so.

//The format of the lines in text file'Month June'

"weekday

'weekend'

'weekend'

//Instead of the output being like this for the two weekends found:

"Month June"

"Month June"

//I want it to return only once like so:

"Month June"

Your Help will be highly appreciated as i am new to c#. I tried implementing LINQ and REGEX but i failed. i guess i am not there yet in terms of proficiency.

Here is my Code:

```
string[] result = list.ToArray();
     for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
           {

             if (result[i].Contains("weekend"))
                {

                var request = result[i];

                            ult = result[i - 1];
                            ault = result[i - 2];

                            if (ult.Contains("Month"))
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(ult + "\r\n");          
                            }

                            if (ault.Contains("Month"))
                            {
                            Console.WriteLine(ault + "\r\n");
                        }

                    }
                }
```

Comment: What does this have to do with regex? or linq? just search for month then read all weekends till you find month again

Comment: Did you checked my answer.It might be not accurate as your requirement is not clear but logic and way of coding will be same.Try and let me know if it helped

Comment: @Lara: It wasn't accurate as to how i wanted it to function but it gave me an idea of what i should do and i was able to resolve the problem. Forgive me for not being clear enough. Thank you very much anyway. :)

Comment: @Kampion If it helped,Mark as answer and upvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your textfile name is "Sample.txt" and contains below

```
Month Jan
Month Feb 
Month March 
Weekend
```

is the textfile which you want to traverse to meet the purpose.In this case your code is supposed to be like ..

```
            using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText("Sample.txt"))
            {
            string s = String.Empty;
            while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (!(s.Contains("Weekend")))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(s);
                }
                else
                {
                    sr.Close();
                }
            }
            }
```

Above code will solve your issue.